# how I can get all the actions in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-plugin

I want to custom a ElasticsearchClient, but I have some problems.
when I try to deserialize Action from it's name, I found that I cannot find the actions register holder.How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve. Please update your question listing the steps you're taking as well as expected and actual results.

Comment: We want to add a layer of proxy service before the request reaches the ES server, that is, request - > proxy layer - > es server. Our scheme is: request (using `CustomElasticsearchClient`) - > serialize the request - > proxy layer - > deserialize the request - > call the real es server. In the method parameter of `ElasticsearchClient` interface, we need to provide `Action` instances according to the name of `Action` when deserializing the request. What should we do to get all Action instances?